# How to modify HTTP headers in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to modify HTTP header like adding x-MSISDN and user-agent
And with the solution given

I tried below code

````
    describe('The Home Page', function() {


  it('successfully loads', function() {

      cy.server()

      cy.route({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/sdp",
  headers: {
     "x-msisdn": "7845851265",
     "User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/8.0.35626/37.8186; U; ru) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16"
     }
})

    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/sdp') // Dev URL 
    cy.get("[class='activateBtn']").click()
    expect('true').to.equal('true')
  })
})```
````

Comment: > You can't currently stub any options of a request unless you also stub the response.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/190#issuecomment-383606850

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna do something like this instead:

```
cy.server()

cy.route({
  method: [your_method e.g "GET"],
  url: [your_url e.g "/login"],
  headers: {
     'x-msisdn': '7845851265',
   ... etc ...
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but did not worked: I have modified my question with your solution

Comment: What is the error message? What are you trying to test?

Comment: I am not getting error, but my headers are not getting set when I run test case.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do. But I came across a few issues not understanding cy.visit() well. It shouldn’t be used for navigation but rather for the initial rendering of the app. So I am not sure you could stub a route and then use the headers with visit(). This caveat aside, I believe you are trying to run your test as if opera was the browser, but Cypress isn’t cross browser yet, Chrome only for the moment.

Comment: Thanks Yannick for your valuable time and solution provided. Actually my question was not to test API by passing headers. My question is for Passing headers in HTTP request of browser. As per my research this is not yet possible with cypress.

Comment: Solution to use Headers in HTTP request is by selecting any modify header in browser and then using "test": "cypress run --browser chrome", in package.Json file and in command line use npm run test

Answer (score 0):

you can make all request add a custom header like

```
cy.server({
  headers: {
    'x-token': 'abc-123-foo-bar'
  }
});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Options